# ROS does not detect packages installed with apt-get

Tags: ros, package, roscd, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I tried to install packages to ROS indigo by running the command: sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-*package name*

The packages are downloaded and installed but neither roscd nor rosrun can find them, despite sourcing the file setup.bash after the download.

Am I missing a step?

Best Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202060/ros-does-not-detect-packages-installed-with-apt-get/) by [Audren Cloitre](https://answers.ros.org/users/21522/audren-cloitre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could be that your cache is (somehow) out-of-date. Try a `rospack profile` after you've sourced `setup.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Audren Cloitre](https://answers.ros.org/users/21522/audren-cloitre/) on 2015-01-29**:
Thank you so much gvdhoorn!
It worked and ROS can now retrieve the packages installed. All good.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-29**:
Np. Please mark the question as answered by clicking the check mark.